# Runtime error while using FileStorage in Opencv

Tags: .net, opencv, visual-c++

Here is a code from Opencv Documentation that uses FileStorage for writing XML/YAML files:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <time.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int, char** argv) {
FileStorage fs("test.yml", FileStorage::WRITE);

fs << "frameCount" << 5;
time_t rawtime; time(&rawtime);
fs << "calibrationDate" << asctime(localtime(&rawtime));
Mat cameraMatrix = (Mat_<double>(3,3) << 1000, 0, 320, 0, 1000, 240, 0, 0, 1);
Mat distCoeffs = (Mat_<double>(5,1) << 0.1, 0.01, -0.001, 0, 0);
fs << "cameraMatrix" << cameraMatrix << "distCoeffs" << distCoeffs;
fs << "features" << "[";
for( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
{
    int x = rand() % 640;
    int y = rand() % 480;
    uchar lbp = rand() % 256;

    fs << "{:" << "x" << x << "y" << y << "lbp" << "[:";
    for( int j = 0; j < 8; j++ )
        fs << ((lbp >> j) & 1);
    fs << "]" << "}";
}
fs << "]";
fs.release();
return 0;
}
```

Whenever I run this code, I always get this error:

`OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (Incorrect element name É1Z) in unknown function
, file c:\Users\vp\work\ocv\opencv\modules\core\src\persistence.cpp, line 5090`

How to solve this issue ?

Comment: Does this have anything to do with encoding of th XML file ?

Comment: Was this ever solved?
I am having the same thing.
In tracking it, it appears that the error arises the first time you use the "[" bracket. Also, the documentation appears off.
The example specifies yml but the text claims that it will output xml.